# Country geocode borders - getting rid of state lines

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocode

recently started messing with Google Maps API, and wanted to create a custom map with certain countries highlighted (I know - classic problem). There are multiple topics on this in here already and I went through them already.

When I try to do this using 'country' tables, their polygon data is horrible. The output becomes something like this:

[image]

I came across with another dataset today called Geocodezip. And here is the code I use (inherited from another post here and tweaked a little) and the output I see when I draw it (deleted the API key from the code)

```
<html>
  <head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 40, lng: 25},
zoom: 6
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col38",
        from: "19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA",
        where: "col2 in ('GRC')"
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 9,
        templateId: 8

      }
    });

  layer.setMap(map);
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=__my_API_key_here__&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

[image]

The difference is overwhelming, and I'd like to proceed with the second map. Yet it has state borders in it as well as the country border. I only need the country border.. Is there a way to use the second dataset country borders only? How do I eliminate them?

P.S.: Also can you tell me how to edit the drawing color? Couldn't find styleID descriptions for Geocodezip

Comment: Did you browse the fusion tables for other data sets?

Comment: There are many... https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1U0btOu3u0TN1S1Rp_7JHwdAf-GGB7LEbJ5lUA4u0#map:id=3 or https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1li5748Nntp9xk1Vbq2lHzzenhekkxKOx4o7ZkdiI#map:id=3 - just go to http://research.google.com/tables?corpus=fusion and search for what you need "countries geometry" for example or be more specific if you need only some countries (geometry might be more accurate).

Comment: @MrUpsidown hey, thanks for the suggestion! Those country geometries are also looking like the top example I had when I zoom a bit, not drawn very accurately. Geocodezip looks VERY solid compared to any other table.

Comment: Also I found this today - with a bit of digging the source code, the right query should be extractable. Not sure how though: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_worldmap_linkto.html?lat=38.946755&lng=21.976643&zoom=6&type=m&tableid=419167&tablequery=SELECT%20kml_4326%20FROM%20419167%20WHERE%20sovereignt%20%3D%20%27Greece%27

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured out the answer on my own after looking into source code of the other example I discovered. Turns out what I look for is on another table:

```
from: "419167",
where: "sovereignt in ('Greece')"
```

Just changed the two lines above and it's working perfectly.